# Detect if connection is wifi, 3G or EDGE in android?

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I need to detect in android if there is any connection `Wifi` or `3G` ( or `3G+`) or `EDGE` in android. When there is an connection `wifi` or `3G` I can send photos to server, and when is only a connection `EDGE` to not send them to server.

I saw that wifi connectivity can be detected with `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` and with `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` and `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE` can be detected EDGE connection. But how can be detected 3G or 3G+?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511564/how-to-check-whether-3g-is-active-or-not-in-android. Check this link. May help you.

Comment: Check this answer. It might help you


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android/8548926#8548926

Answer (score 40):

https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5130324

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

/**
 * Check device's network connectivity and speed 
 * @author emil http://stackoverflow.com/users/220710/emil
 *
 */
public class Connectivity
{
    /**
     * Get the network info
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is fast connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                    return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                    return false; // ~ 100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
                    return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                    return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                    return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                    return false; // ~25 kbps 
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                    return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
                // Unknown
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class WifiState {

    Context context;

    public WifiState(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void haveNetworkConnection() {

        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;

        }
        if (haveConnectedWifi == false && haveConnectedMobile == false) {

            //do something to handle if wifi & mobiledata is disabled

        } else {
                 //do something else..
        }
    }
```

Comment: MOBILE case means it is connected 3G ??

Comment: according to the documentation; Yes.     http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_MOBILE

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen may I make the suggestion: `ni.isConnected()` being called before `getTypeName()` being called. It is purely aesthetic, decreasing 2 lines of replicated code.

Answer (score -1):

First get a reference to the ConnectivityManager and then [check the Wifi and 3G status](http://d.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) of the device.
You'll need the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission to use this service.

```
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (mWifi.isAvailable() == true) {
        return "Connected to WiFi";
    } else if (mMobile.isAvailable() == true) {
        return "Connected to Mobile Network";
    } else return "No internet Connection"
```